# How to mock only one static method and test the other

Tags: java, jmockit

```
@Mocked Provider provider;

public static class Provider {
    public static List<Integer> getStaticList() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static List<Integer> test() {
        return getStaticList();
    }
}

@Test
public void testStatic() {
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);

    new Expectations() {
        {
            Provider.getStaticList();
            result = list;
        }
    };

    assertThat(Provider.test(), JUnitMatchers.hasItem(1));
}
```

I want to mock (with JMockit) one static method that is called within another one. How can I do that? The above test fails. The real Provider.test method is never called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use partial mocking:

```
@Test
public void testStatic() {
    new Expectations(Provider.class) {{ Provider.getStaticList(); result = 1; }};

    List<Integer> test = Provider.test();

    assertTrue(test.contains(1));
}
```

(With no "`@Mocked Provider`" field for the test above.)

Answer (score 11):

The code below changes the behaviour of `doSomething` static method only, without affecting other static methods.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Foo.class})
public class Snipets {

    @Test
    public void hoge() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.spy(Foo.class);
        PowerMockito.when(Foo.class, "doSomething").thenReturn("dummy");

        String actual = Foo.doSomething();
        assertEquals("dummy", actual);
    }

}
```

Foo.java

```
public class Foo {
    public static String doSomething() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/mid0111/8859159

Comment: Thanks but I know how to do it with PowerMock. I'm currently evaluating wether I should use JMockit in the future.

Comment: I thought the jmockit tag and the jmockit example makes it obvious. I'll add it in text. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It actually call static method while mocking with when.

Comment: Why are you providing a JMock/Powermock asnwer to a JMockit question?  Totally different frameworks

Answer (score 8):

I used a very simple method of writing a conditional answer like this:

```
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(<MyMockedClass>.class, invocation -> {
        if (invocation.getMethod().getName().equals("<methodToMockName>")) {
            return <mockedValue>;
        }
        return invocation.callRealMethod();
    });
```